# RegEx Match a string and capture the following string until following tag

Tags: regex, string

I am trying to capture a part of a string using RegEx but can't i can capture the string itself but not the following string.

Here is the html source i would like to capture from:

```
<div class="FindBoxTopL fl_left">
<b>Salary: </b> $10.00 <br>
<b>Location: </b> Wisconsin Madison<br>
<b>Country:</b>United States<br>

<b>Contract Type: </b>Part Time<br><b>Closing Date: </b>August 15, 2014<br>
</div>
```

From the above html i would like to capture: Wisconsin Madison

So i would match the string Location:\s</b> and then capture the string Wisconsin Madison and stop at the page break.

The end capture output would be: Wisconsin Madison

Can anyone help please?

Comment: There is a better way to do this, use a parser. What language?

Comment: [Please remember the usual admonition against using Regex on (X)HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Hi i am using Powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex :

```
/(?<=Location:\s\<\/b\>\s)(.+?)(?=\<br\>)/g
```

Explanations :

- `(?<=Location:\s\<\/b\>\s)` : lookbehind, your string **must** follow `Location </b>`
- `(?=\<br\>)` : lookahead, your string **must** be followed by `<br>`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Try it !](http://regex101.com/r/xH4dA2/2)**

Comment: This matches but does not capture the string Wisconsin Madison

Answer (score 3):

Use the right tool for the job instead of trying to parse **HTML** using regular expressions. I would take advantage of using the [Html Agility Pack](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2010/03/05/html-agility-pack-rocks-your-screen-scraping-world/) which would make this alot easier trying to parse and extract values.

If you still choose to use a regular expression for this, you can use the following:

```
<b>Location:\s*</b>\s*([^<]*)
```

Use capturing group `#1` to access your match result.

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/iX5fB2/1)